# Why can't i set the height of the bottom tab bar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have global variables set in a gloabls.js file which work perfectly and get set in my App.js file fine. e.g.

```
    global.App_paddingLeft = 3,
    global.App_BottomTabBarHeight = '8%',
```

In my App.js i do this:

```
//Tabs across the bottom of the screen
const MainScreenTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
    
    OtherStack,

  },
  {

    tabBarOptions: {

      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black', //white 
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff8278',
        height: global.App_BottomTabBarHeight   //'8%'
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
      },
      showLabel: false
    },
    
  }
  
);
```

The height wont set with the variable `global.App_BottomTabBarHeight = '8%'`. This `global.App_BottomTabBarHeight` definitely passes the '8%' through to the App.js file as i've console.logged it.

I've also tried doing this:
`height: Dimensions.get('window').height * global.App_BottomTabBarHeight`, where `global.App_BottomTabBarHeight = 0.08`, but still nothing

Why can't i set the height to '8%' ?

If i manually type `height: '8%'` it works fine. Strange

Comment: Could you try attaching your global variables to the `window`?

Comment: So I was thinking the issue is that this file is no accessible by that function so if you attached those global variables to the `window` object maybe that would help. I want to also know where does this sit? Is this in an HTML file or in Node.js?

Comment: The global variables sit in a globals.js file in the same folder as my App.js file. I can access dozens of global variables that are numbers in the current setup. However i cant set the height. I know the variable is definitely being passed to my App.js file where in need it. It just won't set as the height. Whether its the '8%' or whether its a number 0.08, height just won't set

Comment: This might be so dumb but could you try height: `${global.App_BottomTabBarHeight}`. When you console.log(global.App_BottomTabBarHeight) in that file what do you see?

Comment: global.App_BottomTabBarHeight is not a file it's a value. so it's currently set = '8%'. If i set it = '0.08', the height: global.App_BottomTabBarHeight still wont recognize it. But if i type height: '8%' or height: '0.08' it does. So the value (although it definitely exists), is not being accepted by the height:

Comment: Yeah I get its a value. What do you see if you `console.log` it? What does it show up as?

Comment: Shows up as '8%' as expected. Or 0.08 as expected. I even did an Alert.alert( global.App_BottomTabBarHeight) and the values appear as expected. When setting it as height: in the style{} it fails